# How do you replace "</div>" in a string?

Tags: javascript, html, replace, textarea, global

I'm working with textarea.  Its value contains `<div>` and `</div>` for some weird reason.  So I'm trying to replace the textarea's value with a string that doesn't include `</div>`.  I'm expecting there to be more than one `</div>`, depending on the value.  I got `<div>` down:

```
document.getElementById("textarea'sname").value.replace(/<div>/g,"");
```

But I'm struggling with globally removing `</div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex for this too and just escape the `/` by placing a `\` in front of it.

```js
let a = "test </div> test test hi im </div>";
let b = a.replace(/<\/div>/g, "");

console.log(b)
```